# Strange error when trying to discover MSTest tests in Visual Studio (.NET Core 7): "TestRunDirectoryLabel"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, mstest

I recently migrated a C# project from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET Core 7. In the new version, MSTest is failing to discover any of my unit tests. When I check out the old framework branch the tests in that branch show up fine. Also, until a couple of weeks ago I was able to run the tests on the new branch, and it does not seem like anything has changed in the codebase since then which would affect this.. Other developers on this project are able to run the tests fine, so I think this is some kind of machine-specific problem, rather than any problem with the code state or Nuget packages. I get this message from the Output -> Tests pane on rebuild:

```
Building Test Projects
Starting test discovery for requested test run
========== Starting test discovery ==========
[MSTest][Discovery][C:\sln\project\bin\Debug\project.dll] Failed to discover tests from assembly C:\sln\project\bin\Debug\project.dll. Reason:Field not found: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestContext.TestRunDirectoryLabel'.
No test is available in C:\sln\project\bin\Debug\project.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
========== Test discovery finished: 0 Tests found in 993.5 ms ==========
```

Does anyone recognize this error? How can I fix it? Thanks.

Here's my .runsettings file, in case it's relevant.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
    <!-- Configurations that affect the Test Framework -->
    <RunConfiguration>
        <!-- Path relative to solution directory -->
        <ResultsDirectory>.\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>

        <!-- [x86] | x64  
      - You can also change it from menu Test, Test Settings, Default Processor Architecture -->
        <TargetPlatform>x64</TargetPlatform>

        <!-- Framework35 | [Framework40] | Framework45 -->
        <!--<TargetFrameworkVersion>Framework40</TargetFrameworkVersion>-->
    </RunConfiguration>

    <!-- Configurations for data collectors -->
    <DataCollectionRunSettings>
        <DataCollectors>
            <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage" uri="datacollector://Microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken="[redacted]">
                <Configuration>
                    <CodeCoverage>
                        <ModulePaths>
                            <Exclude>
                                <ModulePath>.*CPPUnitTestFramework.*</ModulePath>
                            </Exclude>
                        </ModulePaths>
                    </CodeCoverage>
                </Configuration>
            </DataCollector>

        </DataCollectors>
    </DataCollectionRunSettings>

    <!-- Adapter Specific sections -->

    <!-- MSTest adapter -->
    <MSTest>
        <!-- required for app.config (which has gcverylargeobjects) to run -->
        <!--<ForcedLegacyMode>true</ForcedLegacyMode>-->
        <MapInconclusiveToFailed>True</MapInconclusiveToFailed>
        <CaptureTraceOutput>false</CaptureTraceOutput>
        <DeleteDeploymentDirectoryAfterTestRunIsComplete>false</DeleteDeploymentDirectoryAfterTestRunIsComplete>
        <DeploymentEnabled>true</DeploymentEnabled>
    </MSTest>
```

I tried deleting all .vs, bin, and obj directories and rebuilding, installing various MSTest-related Nuget packages, adjusting things in the .runsettings file, updating .NET Core and .NET Framework, and attempting to run the tests with the dotnet command line interface. None changed the error.

Comment: What is the name of your test project ??  `project` is your test Project ? ... make sure that you run the correct test project

Comment: Hello, here is a similar [MSTestAdapter failed to discover tests in class](https://github.com/microsoft/testfx/issues/1256). Hope it can help you

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using? Did you install updates for Visual Studio recently?

Comment: using SDK style csproj files for framework 4.8 and my tests run in Azure DevOps CI pipeline just fine - but I do see this exact error on my local IDE (VS 2022)

Answer (score 0):

Running into the same issue, except I get this error when I try to run the unit tests, recovery works and strangely enough on other systems this doesn't happen.
Also when I look at the TestContext class fields, the mentioned "missing" field is there so I assume it's some kind of version mismatch/it uses something else when running the unit tests than what is used in visual studio itself.

Ok it works again after I switched the log level for tests to "Trace" the error was gone even when switching back to "Information".
Thanks visual studio...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you fixed this but I believe this is caused by package dependencies not being satisfied.  I have seen similar but if I run the same tests in Visual Studio it gives a more useful error, failing the tests and complaining about unsatisfied dependencies.  On a CI environment it often just gives this error instead.